# Evaluate $\int_0^1x^a e^x dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate the definite integral $$
> \int_0^1x^a e^x dx
> $$

Can I use Feynman technique(or Leibniz rule) here or what is the best approach in such type of problems ?

$$
I(a)=\int_0^1x^a e^x dx=\int_1^e(\log x)^adx\\
I'(a)=\int_0^1x^{a}.\log x. e^x dx
$$
**Note**: I could only find $\int_0^1x^3 e^x dx=\int_1^e(\log x)^3dx=6-2e$ by integration by parts technique.

I was expecting this to be solved as we solve for the gamma function using Leibniz rule

Set $x=tu\implies dx=tdu$,
$$
I=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}dx=1\implies\int_0^\infty te^{-tu}du=1\implies\int_0^\infty e^{-tu}du=\frac{1}{t}
$$
Leibniz rule
$$
\frac{d}{dt}I(t)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial t}e^{-tu}du=\int_0^\infty -u e^{-tu}du=\frac{-1}{t^2}\\
\implies\int_0^\infty u e^{-tu}du=\frac{1}{t^2}\implies\int_0^\infty u^2 e^{-tu}du=\frac{2}{t^3}\implies\\
\int_0^\infty u^n e^{-tu}du=\frac{n!}{t^{n+1}}\implies\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{t^n}e^{-x}\frac{dx}{t}=\frac{n!}{t^{n+1}}\implies\boxed{\color{red}{\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}dx=n!}}
$$

Comment: Use the gamma function.

Comment: Is $a$ a real ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes. +ve integers.

Comment: I meant non-integer :)

Comment: $a\in\mathcal{Z}^+$, well I am not sure about other real numbers.

Comment: Assuming that $a$ is real, you must have $a>-1$ in order to the integral to be convergent (this is relevant for $a<0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By parts,

$$I_a:=\int_0^1 x^ae^x\,dx=\left.x^ae^x\right|_0^1-a\int_0^1 x^{a-1}e^x\,dx=e-aI_{a-1}.$$

This gives you a recurrence relation which works for integer $a$, together with $I_0=e-1$.

---

For non-integer $a$, I am afraid that you have to resort to an incomplete Gamma integral. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function. Take care to change the sign of the variable.

Comment: How about Feynman technique, any hope with that ?

Comment: @ss1729, what do you mean by hope? The result is what it is, be it elementary function or not. It won't change if you use another technique.

Comment: @ss1729: I gave you an easy solution, what more do you want ?

Comment: @Ennar Sorry about the word "hope" there in case it is misunderstood, I was expecting this problem is easily solvable by the Leibniz rule as the integral for the factorial, or the gamma function.

Comment: @ss1729: where did you see that the Gamma integral can be addressed by the Leibnitz rule ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust Set $x=tu\implies dx=tdu$,$
I=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}dx=1\implies\int_0^\infty te^{-tu}du=1\implies\int_0^\infty e^{-tu}du=\frac{1}{t}\implies$
Leibniz rule
$\frac{d}{dt}I=\int_0^\infty \frac{d}{dt}e^{-tu}du=\int_0^\infty -u e^{-tu}du=\frac{-1}{t^2}\implies\int_0^\infty u e^{-tu}du=\frac{1}{t^2}\implies\int_0^\infty u^2 e^{-tu}du=\frac{2}{t^3}\implies\int_0^\infty u^n e^{-tu}du=\frac{n!}{t^{n+1}}\implies\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{t^n}e^{-x}\frac{dx}{t}=\frac{n!}{t^{n+1}}\implies\boxed{\color{red}{\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}dx=n!}}$

Comment: @ss1729: this is ridiculous. It is working with the same recurrence that you easily establish by parts, but in a more indirect and contrived way.